# URL generation failing after critical update "Require Customize Application permission for direct read access to custom settings"

Tags: critical-update

I have a application setting that is failing to be accessed through apex code when the below critical update is activated:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_custom_settings_access_cruc.htm

The code just checks if the app settings are not null and if they aren't then it appends those values to the url with the specific values from specific app settings.

```
List<String> urlParameters = new String[] {AppSettings.url__c, AppSettings.idValue__c;
Url = String.format('{0}?id={1}', urlParameters);
```

I know I can fix this by providing "customize application settings" permission but is there any way around this without giving that permission?

Comment: It mentions "Custom Settings retrieved using Apex code will continue to work after this update". Are you sure the error is due to this? If so, it might be worthwhile to create a support case to get some clarification

Comment: Thanks Kris. I believe the custom settings require a new setting to be enabled for a user to have access for just reading the custom setting. Previously I didn't want to give them access to read edit and write.